# The server at www.localhost.com is taking too long to respond. asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to run my website in visual studio 2008. It shows error message like:

> The server at www.localhost.com is taking too long to respond.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

I also run new project Print Label "helloworld" still throws same error

Comment: Does it *really* say `www.localhost.com`? If so, that sounds like the problem to start with...

Comment: Stop the IIS Express Service and Check again.Check the Start URL in Project Properties

Comment: May not be your issue, but try http://localhost.com  `www` is a subdomain, and the DNS might do something funky with that.

Comment: It should say `localhost` without any subdomains or TLDs.

Comment: `www.localhost.com` is unavailable, so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: How about disable Loopback Check ?

Comment: i am not using IIS server, i was run my web site on visual studio 2008

Comment: even new project contain only lable which print "hello world", shows same message on browser

Answer (score 1):

Change the url from your browser from www.localhost.com to localhost only. Usually, after 'localhost' is the name of your application. Sometimes, the browsers are trying to connect you to another domain if they detect that you might misspelled the url address. Might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Check if any blocking from your firewall settings, in my local when I turn off the firewall, it works. So if need add your port in firewall rules or simply turn off the firewall to test the site.

Answer (score 0):

Same like the answers above, it should be only localhost. It's only itself a `hostname` to access your own computer's network services. If changing to localhost in your browser `url` doesn't work, try this one:

1) Go to Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Services

2) Start or Restart `ASP .NET State Service`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have an entry in your hosts file for the "local" IP.
i.e. It needs to be your internal Lan IP. such as 192.168.1.XXX or what ever schema you use.....

The path for your hosts file should be something like this on your server

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

The hosts file does not have an extension.... such as .txt or anything.

Sometimes, if you have a server on your local network, and you need to use it on a particular machine, you may need to include the IP or DNS Name in your hosts file, such as:

MyServerName                          MyWebSiteName

FredServer1                           FredWorld.com